# Web Scrapping - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

Quando Header Cache-Control é private, isso quer dizer que não é possível acessar formulário pelo Requests? Ideia era coletar da fonte Pública, os dados médios do combustível de todas as cidades de todos os estados mas não encontro Parâmetros para aplicar.

Fonte: https://preco.anp.gov.br/include/Resumo_Por_Estado_Index.asp

[image: Preco_site_ANP]

Comment: Cache e request de scrap não tem relação nenhuma. Você pode [edit] a pergunta e elaborar melhor seu problema, que ela entra numa fila de reavaliação. Se tiver relação com algum código seu, pode incluir um [mcve] do problema para esclarecer melhor (não o código original, leia o link). Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 2):

Quando o cabeçalho `cache-control` possui o valor `private`. Isso significa que uma parte ou a resposta da requisição (completa) não deve utilizar um cache compartilhado, quer dizer que apenas um usuário pode ter acesso a esse cache, entenda como um cache exclusivo para um indivíduo, outro usuário em outra sessão não pode receber o mesmo cache (teoricamente) pelo servidor da aplicação.

Ainda na documentação é dito que o uso da palavra `private` só significa que a resposta não deve ser compartilhada em cache, e não tem relação com o fato da informação ser restrita (privacidade da informação).

Segundo a [`referência`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Estando no link da referência, procurar por: ***14.9.1 What is Cacheable***

Comment: Esta errado, `private` indica sim que pode ser armazenado em cache, o que ele quer dizer é que o comportamento não deve ser um cache compartilhado, quer dizer que apenas um usuário pode ter acesso a esse cache, entenda como um cache exclusivo para um indivíduo, outro usuário em outra sessão não pode receber o mesmo (teoricamente), isso é resolvido pelo "lado cliente" (pelo navegador, por exemplo). Para indicar para o cliente que não é para criar cache a opção é `no-cache`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, vlw, remendei

Comment: Essa resposta seria boa para uma pergunta especificamente sobre Cache-Control, devo dizer que a pergunta atual não esta legal e não facilita a encontrar a resposta, acaso alguém tenha duvida semelhante, até mesmo o titulo não esta bom. Seria legal se o pessoal da comunidade, estou falando de geral não de ti, colocasse esforço em aproveitar os assuntos de perguntas assim para elaborar perguntas mais objetivas para servir de conteúdo para o site e fechassem as perguntas que geralmente só servem ao AP.

Comment: Vou tentar adaptar, tem como passar pela revisão dps de adaptar?

Comment: @Danizavtz a revisão é pra perguntas. Mesmo que a resposta fique ótima, a pergunta no estado atual precisa ser melhorada pelo autor, pq está meio confuso saber qual o problema de fato dele(a) que levou a essa dúvida. (mas isso não impede de você deixar a resposta melhor, se achar que vale o esforço, eu acho meio arriscado). Note que mesmo sabendo o que é o cache-control, não deveria influenciar em scrap de nada.

Comment: Não recomendo editar a pergunta do AP, isso vai contra o interesse, pois o autor pode falar de X, mas o problema na verdade pode ser Y. O importante é fechar e ser o assunto for muito bom, [elaborar uma pergunta que você mesmo pode responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), mas para a maioria dos casos, coisas muito simples, um comentário explicando a diferença de algo + voto de fechamento estará mais do que bom, o importante mesmo é fechar as perguntas mal elaboradas, pois o foco do site é focar no conteúdo que sirva a todos e não na ajuda individual.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento para não contaminar, melhor eu excluir a pergunta?